# Go Gin: Validating base64

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to send a base64 image to my server written in Go using Gin. I created a struct with binding and json tags to represent the request body, it looks as follows:

```golang
type createCompanyRequestBody struct {
    Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Size string `json:"size" binding:"required"`
    Logo string `json:"logo" binding:"required,base64|base64url|base64rawurl"`
}
```

When trying to decode the body using Gin's `ShouldBindJSON`, I get an error for the `Logo` field. I did however verify using an online tool (https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-base64-to-png) that the decoded object does include a valid base64 string in the `Logo` field.

The code used for decoding the JSON is as follows:

```golang
var body createCompanyRequestBody
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&body); err != nil {
    ctx.Status(http.StatusBadRequest) // Will always hit this
}
```

I haven't used Gin before, so I'm sure there is an oversight on my end, but I can't seem to figure out what. How can I change the struct so that it allows the base64 variants provided as intended?

Comment: That’s it! I thought a base64 url and datauri were the same thing. If you’d like and have the time. Can you make your comment an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending the image as a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) rather than just a *bare* `base64` string, then you should use the [`datauri`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Data_URL) validator instead of `base64|base64URL|base64RawURL`.